# Why don't setters and getters work as expected?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setter, getter

This is my first question on Stackoverflow and this is an assignment I am working on. I have exhausted all of my other options before asking for your help.

The code is to create a class that will ask the user to input their pets name, age, and type, and to return the results using the accessor method. This is my first class assignment and I cannot get it to print or return the input. If someone could please explain to me where my problem is, and to point me in the right direction. I'm not sure if my class is wrong, fields, getters, or setters. I feel like I made a simple mistake somewhere and I can't figure it out.

This is python 2.7

```
#Pet class


class Pet():
    def __init__(self, name, typea, age):
        self.name = name
        self.typea = typea
        self.age = age

def main():
    pet_name =raw_input('What is your pets name? ')
    pet_typea =raw_input('What type of animal is your pet? ')
    pet_age =raw_input('What is your pets age? ')

    def __setName__(self, n):
        self.name = n
    def __getName__(self, n):
        return self.n

    def __setTypea__(self, t):
        self.typea = t
    def __getTypa__(self, t):
        return self.t

    def __setAge__(self, a):
        self.age = a
    def __getAge__(self, a):
        return self.a

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be misunderstanding how classes work in Python. Presumably, you want the `__setName__` methods to be inside the `class Pet` scope. The `main` function is not part of your class and defining functions there is not going to affect anything. Also, you've redefined the `__setName__` method multiple times. Presumably, you want those to be called `__setType__` and `__setAge__` and so on. Also, it is very unusual in Python to start your method names with double underscores. That is usually reserved for special methods like `__init__`. Regular methods should just be called `setAge` for example. Also, [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) says that method names should not be camel case, but instead use underscores to separate words. So the more Pythonic name would be `set_name`. However, Python typically doesn't use `set_*` or `get_*` methods at all and prefers to use [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) instead.

Finally, if you're truly using Python 2.7, then you should probably be using "new-style" objects, which means you should change your `class` definition line to inherit from `object` as well.

Try starting from here instead:

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, typea, age):
        self.name = name
        self.typea = typea
        self.age = age

    def setName(self, n):
        self.name = n
    def getName(self, n):
        return self.n

    def setType(self, t):
        self.typea = t
    def getType(self, t):
        return self.t

    def setAge(self, a):
        self.age = a
    def getAge(self, a):
        return self.a

def main():
    pet_name =raw_input('What is your pets name? ')
    pet_typea =raw_input('What type of animal is your pet? ')
    pet_age =raw_input('What is your pets age? ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Our professor is making us work in 2.7 for some unknown reason. What you wrote made sense and I corrected what I needed to. The only problem I'm still having is the input will not print. Shouldn't the 'return' print the input?

Comment: `return` does not print. That's what `print` does.

Comment: I'm sorry. I realized that after I sent the message

Comment: I was getting around to that haha. I'm new to StackOverFlow. For some reason I still cannot get the input to print. I've spent hours trying to get this code to print. It shouldn't take hours, but I'm still a Python noob. The code is fine, it just doesn't print. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: You could update your question with the new information or ask a new question as a follow up.